# Reuse context in multiple views

Tags: django

I'm very new to Django and in my application I have a dynamic navbar on top. The context are passed in as context. Imagine it looks like this:

```html
<ul>
    {% for link in links %}
    <li><a href="{{ link }}"></a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

The views may look like this:

```py
def nav_links():
    # Display links to first 5 MyModel objects
    objects = MyModel.objects.all()[:5]
    return [o.get_absolute_url() for o in objects]

def index(request):
    return render("request", "app/index.html", context={"links": nav_links()})

def page1(request)
    some_data = ...
    return render("request", "app/page1.html", context={"links": nav_links(), "data": some_data})

def page2(request)
    return render("request", "app/page2.html", context={"links": nav_links()})

...
```

Currently, I need to pass in `links` as context in each of the views. This is obviously bad design.

Is there a way to pass in the same context for all views?

Comment: It does - thank you! A note to others; the accepted answer in the related question is not updated for Django 3. (Just differences in how context_processors are registered - the concept is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a *context processor*, this is a function that each time runs to populate the context. Such context processor looks like your `nav_links`, except that it should be a dictionary with the variable name(s) and corresponding value(s):

```
# app_name/context_processors.py

def links(request):
    from app_name.models import MyModel
    objects = MyModel.objects.all()[:5]
    return {'links': [o.get_absolute_url() for o in objects]}
```

Then you can register the context processor in the `settings.py` with:

```
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # …,
                'app_name.context_processors.links'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Very neat, thanks!